# Docker gitlab-runner x509: cannot validate certificate

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I am running gitlab and gitlab-runner in the 2 docker containters. 
I create self-signed certificates for gitlab following this manual http://clusterfrak.com/sysops/linux/linux_self_signed_certificate/
I can access gitlab from the browser https://my_ip
But when I am trying to register gitlab-runner but I am getting error: 
x509: cannot validate certificate for 192.168.1.46 because it doesn't contain any IP SANs
What can be the issue? 
I also tried to disable ssl validation in config.toml but it is look like I cannot do that in the latest version of gitlab-runner.

I tried hundreds of different options and it is look like I am stuck. 
Maybe somebody had simillar problem. 
Thank you.